# Payoff of an odd indicator of one stock being greater than another

Tags: options, option-pricing, stochastic-calculus, futures, binary-options

Suppose $S_t^1$ and $S_t^2$ are two stocks following GBMs and have current value $s_1$ and $s_2$ respectively.  How can I explicitly compute the payoff
$$
V(t,s_1,s_2)\triangleq \mathbb{E}\left[
1_{\{S_T^1>S_t^2\}}
\mid S_t^1=s_1,\, S_t^2=s_2
\right],
$$
where $T\geq t$ and $1$ is the indicator function of the event that $S_T^1$ will exeed the value of $S_T^2$ at time $T$.

Comment: you need the correlation and the volatility data.

Comment: Suppose I know those

Comment: Then it is a Bivariate Normal probability problem.

Comment: @noob2 if you give more details I'll accept your answer :)

Answer (score 2):

The price is

$e^{-r(T-t)} \mathbb{P}(S_{T}^{1} > S_{T}^2) =e^{-r(T-t)} \mathbb{P}(S_{T}^{1} / S_{T}^2 >1) $

The crucial point is that the ratio of two log-normals is log-normal even when they are not perfectly correlated so it just comes down to a cumulative normal.

We assume vols are $\sigma_1$ and $\sigma_2$. Correlation between driving BMs is $\rho.$

Let $C_{11} = \sigma_{1}^{2}(T-t),C_{22} = \sigma_{2}^{2}(T-t), C_{12} = \rho \sigma_1 \sigma_2(T-t).$

We can write
$$
S_{T}^{1}= S_{t}^{1} e^{-0.5 C_{11} + \sqrt{C_{11}} Z},$$
$$
S_{T}^{2}= S_{t}^{2} e^{-0.5 C_{22} + \sqrt{C_{22}} (\rho Z + \sqrt{1-\rho^2}W)},$$
with $W$ and $Z$ independent standard normals.

So
$$
S_{T}^{1} / S_{T}^2 = \frac{S_{t}^{1}}{S_{T}^{2}} e^{-0.5 C_{11} +0.5 C_{22} + \sqrt{C_{11}} Z- \sqrt{C_{22}} (\rho Z + \sqrt{1-\rho^2}W)}.
$$
The rest is straightforward.